# gem update sqlite3-ruby failed on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sqlite

This is the command I gave in command prompt:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby > sqlite3-ruby.txt
```

This is the content of sqlite3-ruby.txt

> Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32...

Rest of the command prompt was full of the following:

> ...
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16le
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16be
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_type
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_blob
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_double
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error16
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int64
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16le
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16be
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_value
>   No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_aggregate_context
>   ...

While trying to create a database, I tried the following in command prompt:

```
rake db:create
```

A message box pops up saying that sqlite3.dll is missing. I need to reinstall the application. I tried `gem update sqlite3-ruby` command again and same thing happened.

How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a silly answer, but did you install sqlite3?

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: The command "gem install sqlite3-ruby" is supposed to install sqlite3. Am I wrong? Then what does these messages mean:
"Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32"
"1 gem installed"

Comment: No. `gem install sqlite3-ruby` installs the sqlite3-ruby RubyGem. The SQLite3-Ruby RubyGem provides access to SQLite3, but in order to do that, SQLite3 obviously has to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

> A message box pops up saying that sqlite3.dll is missing

Well, is it?

Comment: Yes it is. I searched ruby installation folder and windows folder for that file and couldn't find it. I'm not sure if sqlite3 installed correctly. Please check my comment in PreciousBodilyFluids's answer.